# quotient homeomorphic to $S^2 \times S^1$?

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

I have the following question:

> Let $M$ be the quotient space $\mathbb{R}^3\backslash\{0\}$ obtained by identifying $(x,y,z)$ with $(2^mx,2^my,2^mz)$ for any $m \in \mathbb{Z}$. Is $M$ homeomorphic to $S^2 \times S^1$? Prove your assertion.

I am not exactly sure. The two topological properties I was thinking about was compactness. It seems like the quotient is compact, but I maybe not.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hint: Yes, it is homeomorphic. Use spherical coordinates.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Can you elaborate a little bit more? I can see how this would relate, but do not really understand the details.

Comment: Use spherical coordinates to construct a homeomorphism $R^3-0$ to $S^2\times R$ such that the map $v\mapsto 2v$ becomes $(s, t)\mapsto (s, t+1)$.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I can see that $\mathbb{R}^3 - \{0\}$ is homeomorphic to to $S^2 \times \mathbb{R}$, but I am not sure what you mean by a map $v \to 2v$ becomes $(s,t) \to (s,t+1)$

Answer (score 2):

If you see this as a quotient by the action of $\mathbb{Z}$ on $\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus \{0\}$, you can prove that the set $D=\{ 1 \le x^2+y^2+z^2 \le 2 \}$ is a fundamental domain. Then the quotient is homeomorphic to $D$ quotiented by the same action. But $D$ can also be seen as $S^2 \times [1, 2]$ and the quotient simply associates $S^2 \times \{1\}$ with $S^2 \times \{2\}$, so the original quotient is in fact homeomorphic to $S^2 \times [1, 2]/\{1, 2\}$ which is indeed equivalent to $S^2 \times S^1$.